# Discord bitwise permission calculator

Tags: php, api, bitwise-operators, discord

I'm trying to let my tool/script determine if a logged in user has the correct permission to use the tool. however Discord is responding with a permission int.

It seems that I have to check permission using a bitwise operator, But from everything that i've googled or searched almost everything I find seems completely irrelevant.

Example Permission: `2146958591`

**Permission references;**

`// General
generalCreateInstantInvite: 0x1,
generalKickMembers: 0x2,
generalBanMembers: 0x4,
generalAdministrator: 0x8,
generalManageChannels: 0x10,
generalManageServer: 0x20,
generalChangeNickname: 0x4000000,
generalManageNicknames: 0x8000000,
generalManageRoles: 0x10000000,
generalManageWebhooks: 0x20000000,
generalManageEmojis: 0x40000000,
generalViewAuditLog: 0x80,
// Text
textAddReactions: 0x40,
textReadMessages: 0x400,
textSendMessages: 0x800,
textSendTTSMessages: 0x1000,
textManageMessages: 0x2000,
textEmbedLinks: 0x4000,
textAttachFiles: 0x8000,
textReadMessageHistory: 0x10000,
textMentionEveryone: 0x20000,
textUseExternalEmojis: 0x40000,
// Voice
voiceViewChannel: 0x400,
voiceConnect: 0x100000,
voiceSpeak: 0x200000,
voiceMuteMembers: 0x400000,
voiceDeafenMembers: 0x800000,
voiceMoveMembers: 0x1000000,
voiceUseVAD: 0x2000000`

Is there a tool or a sample script that I can study, to determine how this calculation is made?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Imagine that you have `4` different actions you want to allow or disallow for each user:

- create post
- update post
- read post
- delete post.

Let's create a 4-characters string of `1` and `0`. The first character in the string represents the user's possibility to `create post` action. The second character – `update post`, third – `read post` and the fourth – `delete post`. For example, if a user has permissions `1001` then he can create posts and delete posts, but can't update and read.

What is the most efficient way to store these permissions? We have only `0` and `1` in every position of our string, so we can store this data not inside the string but inside the binary representation of the number. So, the user's permission will be some decimal number, and every bit of this number will represent permission for a specific action.

For example, our permission string `1001` will be just decimal number `9` (`= 1*2^0 + 0*2^1 + 0*2^2 + 1*2^3`).

We can represent every permission as binary:

- create post = `1000`
- update post = `0100`
- read post = `0010`
- delete post = `0001`

But how can we check that user has specific permission or has a group of permissions? It's easy, let's use bitwise operator `&`:

If user permission equals `9` = `1001`b, then:

- `1001 & 1000 = 1000`, `1000 > 0` – user can create posts
- `1001 & 0100 = 0000`, `0000 == 0` – user can't update posts
- `1001 & 0010 = 0000`, `0000 == 0` – user can't read posts
- `1001 & 0001 = 0001`, `0001 > 0` – user can delete posts

Comment: Bit late to come back on this, but your explanation was on point! Thanks for this!

Comment: thank you for the plain and simple explanation. my javascript implementation


```const operationMapping = {
      1: 'create',
      2: 'read',
      4: 'update',
      8: 'delete',
    };


    let numbers = [1, 2, 4, 8];


    let result = [];


    numbers.map(number => {


      if ((operationId & number) > 0) {


        result.push(operationMapping[number]);


      }


    });


    return result;```

Answer (score 7):

To check if the given permission value has a selected permission, you use a Bitwise AND operator.

Example of this:

```
$canKickMembers = ($permissionCode & 0x2) != 0;
```